# What does const {value:valueFromContext} = useContext(Context) do?

Tags: react-context

I am new to react and I came across the following code:

```
  interface ValueContextProps {
  value?: Object;
  nextValue: (value: Object) => Object;
  }
  const ValueContext = React.createContext<ValueContextProps>({ nextValue: (value) => value });
...

const {nextValue:nextvalueFromContext} = useContext(ValueContext)
```

So what does `nextValue:nextvalueFromContext` do?
What is getting stored in `nextValue`?

Also, valueFromContext is used like a function in the code. Something like -

`nextValue = nextValueFromContext(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an object, then you can destructure the object like this:

```js
const obj = {key: 'value'}

const {key} = obj // this is destructuring

const {key: newVariableName} = obj // this is the same, but key is given a new name

console.log(newVariableName) // 'value'
```

```js
const {nextValue:nextvalueFromContext} = useContext(ValueContext)
```

This will read the value `nextValue` from context, and rename it to `nextValueFromContext`